# how to open a URL using in XSL. which deals with array values

Tags: php, json, xslt

```
foreach( $Uid as $key => $value ){
$a[] = sprintf("%s => %s",$key, $value->id);
```

}
//how to open a url www.asdf.com/uid=123 using XSLT

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$xslt = xslt("<test><example>An example!</example></test>", file_get_contents('http://asdf.com/uid=123'));
var_dump($xslt);

function xslt ($xml, $xsl) {

    $xh = @xslt_create();

    $args['xml'] = ( file_exists( $xml ) )?join ('', file ($xml)):$xml;
    $args['xsl'] = ( file_exists( $xsl ) )?join ('', file ($xsl)):$xsl;

    // try with a string
    $result = @xslt_process ($xh, 'arg:/xml', 'arg:/xsl', NULL, $args);

    // try with resource
    if (!$result) { $result = @xslt_process ($xh, $xml, $xsl); }

    @xslt_free ($xh);
    return $result;

}
?>
```

Comment: i want to open all the urls associated with the $Uid array. ie. $Uid =[123,124,125,126,...] www.asdf.com/uid=123,  www.asdf.com/uid=123,  www.asdf.com/uid=124,  www.asdf.com/uid=125,  and so on... later i have to get the content of each triggered url